# What do the total install and active installs mean in Android Market Developer Console

Tags: google-play

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between total installs and active installs in the Android market?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7336871/what-is-the-difference-between-total-installs-and-active-installs-in-the-android)

I am a bit confused when looking at the Android Market Developer console.

In the console it says that for my app I have:

1617 total installs (users)
285 active installs (devices)

What do these numbers mean because I do not see how I can have more users than I do devices.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When some installs your app, total installs and active installs go up by one.  When someone uninstalls your app, active installs goes down by one.

Total installs is just that, the total number of times your app has been installed.  Active installs is the number of devices that currently have your app installed.